# nesting ng-repeat in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Angular Code:

```
$scope.qA = [ { question : ' question 1', answer: ['answer 1-1', 'answer1-2']},
              { question : ' question 2', answer: ['answer 2-1', 'answer2-2']}];
```

HTML(jade) code

```
h1(ng-repeat='ques in qA.question') {{ques}}
 p(ng-repeat='ans in qA[$index].answer']) {{ans}}
```

In first ng-repeat I want to select the 'question' from qA. In second ng-repeat I want to select each answer for 'question' selected.

The above code is not working. How can it be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
h1(ng-repeat='q in qA') {{ q.question }}
  p(ng-repeat='ans in q.answer']) {{ ans }}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about jade, but this should be somthing like

```
h1(ng-repeat='ques in qA') {{ques}}
 p(ng-repeat='ans in ques.answer']) {{ans}}
```